# How to set canonical hostname in linux?

Tags: java, linux, hostname, neo4j

Question: How do I "set" the canonical hostname as reported by java's `InetAddress.getCanonicalHostname()` method?

Context: I'm trying to run Neo4j (which has an embedded jetty server) on CentOS 5.6.  The service starts up just fine, but it's binding to the wrong address (IPv6) as evidenced by netstat.  Instead of `:::*`, I need it to bind to `0.0.0.0` (IPv4).

Is there a JVM parameter I can use to force `getCanoncialHostname()` to return the string I want?  If not, what can I add to my `hosts` file or other linux config file to achieve the same?

[edit - added netstat output]

```
$ netstat -plten
...
Proto  Local Address    Foreign Address    State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp    0.0.0.0:930      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      0          10240      -
tcp    0.0.0.0:139      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      0          57484      -
tcp    0.0.0.0:111      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      0          10104      -
tcp    127.0.0.1:25     0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      0          12714      -
tcp    0.0.0.0:445      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      0          57483      -
tcp    :::7474          :::*               LISTEN      500        524965     28200/java
tcp    :::22            :::*               LISTEN      0          62967      -
tcp    :::1337          :::*               LISTEN      500        524953     28200/java
tcp    :::15003         :::*               LISTEN      500        481149     3926/java
tcp    :::60156         :::*               LISTEN      500        524951     28200/java
tcp    :::15004         :::*               LISTEN      500        524917     28177/java
```

Port 22 is ssh - I can ssh into the machine just fine, so there's evidence that the `:::*` foreign address is (in principle) just fine.

[edit - added remote nmap output]

Running nmap from another host, specifically listing all the above produces this:

```
$ nmap -T4 -A -v -PE -PS22,25,80 -PA21,23,80,930,139,111,25,445,7474,22,1337,15003,60156,15004,3389 192.168.176.138
...
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 13:31
Scanning 192.168.176.138 [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 111/tcp on 192.168.176.138
Discovered open port 139/tcp on 192.168.176.138
Discovered open port 445/tcp on 192.168.176.138
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 192.168.176.138
Discovered open port 15003/tcp on 192.168.176.138
Discovered open port 15004/tcp on 192.168.176.138
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 13:31, 0.04s elapsed (1000 total ports)
```

Comment: Can't you tell neo4j which interface to bind to?

Comment: I've trolled though the various .properties files that come with neo4j - I have yet to find a setting I can use to affect the interface.  So it's possible, but I don't know how to do it.  I found a class in the source called AddressResolver which uses getCanonicalHostname() while looking for a reference to such a config.

Comment: According to http://www.ipv6verify.com/, `:::*` is not a valid IPv6 address in the first place. The IPv6 equivalent to `0.0.0.0` would be `::` instead. Is it possible it isn't binding to an address at all?

Comment: @JAB: `:::*` means "all ports on `::`", just like `0.0.0.0:*` means all ports on `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I figured that out once jimbojw posted the netstat output. My confusion was mainly caused by his usage of `:::*` vs. `0.0.0.0` rather than `:::*` vs. `0.0.0.0:*` or `::` vs. `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Right - I just added the `netstat` output as well as the result from a remote `nmap` scan.  The 15003 and 15004 ports are bound by a Neo4j spawned process, so I don't understand why other ports (like 7474, the one I actually care about) don't appear to be reachable remotely.  I've had other user spawned servers running on this host (cocuhdb - port 5984 and elastic search - port 9200).  In both cases, they bound to `0.0.0.0` and were reachable remotely.

Comment: Oh yeah, out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you're using `getCanonicalHostname()` rather than `getHostAddress()`?

Comment: Yeah, it's not my code - it's deep in the Neo4j source in a class called [`AddressResolver`](https://trac.neo4j.org/browser/components/server/trunk/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/AddressResolver.java).  I'd prefer not to hack it if there's a pure configuration solution :)

Comment: The Canonical-thing looks up names in DNS and other nasty stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell your JVM to use IPv4 instead of IPv6 via the following network property: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

See [Networking properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)

Comment: Unless he knows for sure there won't be any IPv6 incoming connections, would it not be better for him to make sure `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` is set to `false` instead? Or does `getCanonicalHostname()` ignore that property?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and report back.

Comment: +1, accepted - this did it!  I tried setting `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false` separately.  The former made all the listeners bind to `0.0.0.0` except port `15003` (which I don't care about).  The latter also prevented the binding of `::`, but didn't result in binding `0.0.0.0` - rather nothingwas bound at all.  I haven't tried both options together.

Comment: To make this change in Neo4j specifically:

1. open `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`
2. find the section called "Java Additional Parameters"
3. Add the following line:

    wrapper.java.additional.3=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Answer (score 2):

Maybe setting the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` system property would help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell jetty to listen on specific interface(ip), look here: http://www.paralint.com/blog/2007/05/18/making-jetty-listen-to-the-local-interface-only/

the line:   `<Set name="Host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="localhost"/></Set>`
does that

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Haven't been able to try this yet.  There is no `jettyconf.xml` file, probably because neo4j is embedding it directly. I think neo4j uses the answer to the `getCanonicalHostname()` call to set it.